# Symfony2 Forms conditional validation on empty fields

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I've created a form which has some fields, whose required status is dependend on the value entered into another field (to be specific, whether the value is > 0).

It is about ordering a textbook and if the quantity is > 0, then the address-related fields must also be entered.
I've added a custom validation callback, which can check whether the count is > 0 and then adds a Violation. But it gets only executed if the field is not empty (since it is not "required").

Is there a way to always validate, but without having to use the required flag on the field?

Below a snippet:

```
[...]
$builder->add('firstname', 'text', array(
    'label' => 'label.firstname',
    'required' => false,
    'property_path' => 'Order.firstname',
    'constraints' => array(
        new Callback(array('callback' => array($this, 'validateOrder')))
    )
));
[...]
public function validateOrder($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form */
    $form = $context->getRoot();

    if(
        (
            (int)$form->get('count_d')->getData() > 0 ||
            (int)$form->get('count_f')->getData() > 0 ||
            (int)$form->get('count_i')->getData() > 0
        ) && $data == '') {
        $context->addViolation('profile.order.error');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd create a [class constraint validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more appropriate to put callback at form directly (instead of field)?

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new Callback(array('callback' => array($this, 'validateOrder')))
        )
    ));
}
```

This way, the callback will be invoked in any case...